# Retrieve users ringtone library

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I was wondering if there was a way to retrieve users ringtones or sounds. I am not interested in their music playlist but like 30 second clips of audio that could work for uilocalnotifications. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this answer. 
[how to get the system ringtones programmingly in ios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7455643/how-to-get-the-system-ringtones-programmingly-in-ios)

If you still want to fire an audio notification, this [article](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103) should get you started.
It seems you can assign a filename to the soundName property, or pass `UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName` for (what I would guess is) the user's selected notification sound.

```
- (void)scheduleNotificationWithItem:(ToDoItem *)item interval:(int)minutesBefore {
    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    ...
    [localNotif release];
}
```